# Part of mobile navigation menu items are hidden behind other div

Tags: css, mobile, drop-down-menu, z-index

I'm trying to create a mobile dropdown menu but my menu items are hidden behind another div. I tried using the z-index but apparently I'm doing something wrong...

I created the following JSFiddle to show the problem:
**http://jsfiddle.net/hq160xx2/4/**

As you can see, a part of menu item "Object 2" is hidden behind the "Home" and "Nav2" menu. What should I add to my code so that Object 2 appears on top of the "Home" and "Nav2" menu ?

( Btw: I know that changing the height of `div id="Upper"` could solve the problem, but that's really not what I'm looking for. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `overflow:hidden;` to `overflow:visible;` on the `.upper-mobile` element:

```
.upper-mobile {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Yup! Glad I could help.